# Wso2 Enterprise Integrator mediator filter and external sources

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am new to Enterprise Integrator so I may be facing a misunderstanding problem. I have installed WSO2 EI 6.1.1 on a Linux box. I have created a pass through proxy for a very simple form based web application and it works perfectly.

I want to filter the access to it by previoulsy validating a rest request to an external server. The JSON result of this external request should contain an specific value, f.e. `{"valid":"yes"}`.

I have created a Java class taht can make this call (at the present is just assigning statically the value and loading it in a variable):

```
public class validate extends AbstractMediator { 
    private String validated = "yes";

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        System.out.println("Validating Access!!!!");
        System.out.println("Validated: " + validated);

        return true;
    }

    public String getValidated() {
        return validated;
    }

    public void setValidated(String validated) {
        this.validated = validated;
    }
```

I see it running correctly.

As a second step I have created a Mediator filter with the aim of evaluating this value. I have tested this mediator with an always true xpath expresion `1 > 0` And I see that the then and else clauses work correctly.

I have not been able to check the value obtained in the first mediator in the filter mediator. How can I do this? What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I have found that the apparent way of solving the problem is defining a Property mediator to store the value. I have managed to use a property to make the decision in the filter but, how can I set that property with a value obtained in the Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add this line in your java class :  mc.setProperty("MyPropertyName", myValue);

In your mediation, use get-property("MyPropertyName");

Comment: The correct object is context, so the command would be context.setProperty("MyPropertyName", myValue); but it works.